# Azure Kudu Debug Console not accessible because of DNS error

Tags: azure, console-application, kudu

I created a new Azure Web App (web site) on the path https://todoangular1-b-nschou.azurewebsites.net and I tried to access the Kudu Debug Console by inserting 'scm' between the application name and the domain name. Like this:

https://todoangular1-b-nschou.scm.azurewebsites.net/

However, the site is not available.

Some more research showed that the error was caused by a failing DNS resolution. I then added an entry to my hosts file pointing todoangular1-b-nschou.scm.azurewebsites.net to the same ip-address as todoangular1-b-nschou.azurewebsites.net and suddenly it worked.

My own conclusion is that the Azure platform did not properly add the new DNS-name under the scm.azurewebsites.net zone. Did anyone else experience this odd behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What probably happened is that there was a small delay in DNS propagation. But if you try hitting the site before that, you would then be affected by DNS negative caching on your machine, which can last a little while. My guess is that during that time, if you had tried to access it from a different machine that didn't have the negative caching, it would have worked (and it works fine now).

Comment: Oh, so we have something called negative caching. I didn't know that, but it makes sense and explains my findings. So thx and +1 for that.

Comment: Yes, negative caching is something that's built into the OS as an optimization (at least Windows, but I'm guessing others too). But sometimes it causes pain...

Comment: BTW, if you want to see that, go to somename.azurewebsites.net *before* creating the site, and then create the Azure site. You then won't be able to resolve it for a while even though it's registered.